# How do I scrape websites that do not have html content in the source page

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have this [site](https://info.uniswap.org/#/) I want to scrape data from. I'm trying to extract the data below the two graphs, specifically, **Volume**, **Fees** and **TVL**. The problem is that when I use Selenium, I don't get any elements to access the values. I tried accessing the source page and it also does not have content that is being shown on the page.

How could I scrape such a site?

Here is my code.

```
'''
THIS CODE WILL BE USED TO EXTRACT ETHERIUM DATA FROM UNISWAP V3 SITE
'''
# import required files
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSoup

# base url
eth_uniswap_url = 'https://info.uniswap.org/#/'

# function to get driver
def get_driver():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--headlesss')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    
    webdriver_service = Service("D:\\Software\\Selenium WebDrivers\\chrome_v107\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
    return driver

# function to open site
def access_site(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    bs_Object = BSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    return bs_Object

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('We are going to create the driver')
    
    driver = get_driver()
    
    print('We are now going to access the page')
    
    site_access = access_site(driver, eth_uniswap_url)

    data = site_access.find_all('div', {'class':'sc-jKJlTe sc-hMqMXs sc-hSdWYo eJnjNO'})
    print(len(data))
    print(data)
```

This prints an empty list, meaning that the elements cannot be found in the source page.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the next example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd
webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)

data = []

driver.get('https://info.uniswap.org/#/')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(8)

chart_data = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
graphs = soup.select('div[class="sc-jKJlTe sc-hMqMXs sc-hSdWYo kKrqCm"]')

d = {x.select_one('div[class="sc-chPdSV jOqbNQ css-kep7b5"]').get_text(strip=True) : x.select_one('div[class="sc-chPdSV goKJOd css-szmv65"]').get_text(strip=True) for x in graphs}

chart_data.append(d)
print(chart_data)
# df = pd.DataFrame(chart_data)
# print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Volume 24H:': '$1.35b', 'Fees 24H:': '$1.41m', 'TVL:': '$3.68b'}]
```

Comment: Massive thanks Fazlul! Just so I can understand what I was missing, where did I go wrong?